# Caching requests to reduce processing (TPL?)

Tags: c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm currently trying to reduce the number of similar requests being processed in a business layer by:

1. Caching the requests a method receives
2. Performing the slow processing task (once for all similar requests)
3. Return the result to each requesting method calls

Things to note, are that:

- The original method calls are *not* currently in a async BeginMethod() / EndMethod(IAsyncResult)
- The requests arrive faster than the time it takes to generate the output
- I'm trying to use TPL where possible, as I am currently trying to learn more about this library

eg. Improving the following

```
byte[] RequestSlowOperation(string operationParameter)
{
    Perform slow task here...
}
```

Any thoughts?

Follow up:

```
    class SomeClass
{
    private int _threadCount;

    public SomeClass(int threadCount)
    {
        _threadCount = threadCount;
        int parameter = 0;

        var taskFactory = Task<int>.Factory;

        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
        {
            int i1 = i;

            taskFactory
                .StartNew(() => RequestSlowOperation(parameter))
                .ContinueWith(result => Console.WriteLine("Result {0} : {1}", result.Result, i1));                                                  
        }            
    }

    private int RequestSlowOperation(int parameter)
    {
        Lazy<int> result2;
        var result = _cacheMap.GetOrAdd(parameter, new Lazy<int>(() => RequestSlowOperation2(parameter))).Value;            
        //_cacheMap.TryRemove(parameter, out result2); <<<<< Thought I could remove immediately, but this causes blobby behaviour

        return result;
    }

    static ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<int>> _cacheMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<int>>();
    private int RequestSlowOperation2(int parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Evaluating");
        Thread.Sleep(100);            
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fast, safe and maintainable way to do this:

```
static var cacheMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<byte[]>>();
byte[] RequestSlowOperation(string operationParameter)
{
    return cacheMap.GetOrAdd(operationParameter, () => new Lazy<byte[]>(() => RequestSlowOperation2(operationParameter))).Value;
}

byte[] RequestSlowOperation2(string operationParameter)
{
    Perform slow task here...
}
```

This will execute RequestSlowOperation2 at most once per key. Please be aware that the memory held by the dictionary will never be released.

The user delegate passed to the ConcurrentDictionary is not executed under lock, meaning that it could execute multiple times! My solution allows multiple lazies to be created but only one of them will ever be published and materialized.

Regarding locking: this solution *will* take locks, but it does not matter because the work items are far more expensive than the (few) lock operations.

Comment: Why do you even use `Lazy<T>` here? I think the delegate passed to `GetOrAdd()` won't be executed if a value for that key already exists.

Comment: Should be noted that this isn't avoiding a lock, you're just using a data structure that hides the complexity from you (ConcurrentDictionary).

Comment: Your suggestion is pretty nice usr. I'm just checking out how to clean this dictionary up in my scenario.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: svick, the user delegate is not executed under lock, meaning that it could execute multiple times! My solution allows multiple lazies to be created but only one of them will ever be published and materialized.

Comment: Regarding locking, this is true, but does not matter because the work items are far more expensive than a lock. @OP: Don't be obsessed with avoiding locks. Ask first, if they even matter.

Comment: Have posted my prototype above. (I've replaced the initial parameter and response parameter with ints for simplicity). Note that Lazy<int> result2 is only removed once, and hence is not safe, while int result is safe.

Comment: Looks entirely correct. I would put this into production IF the amount of keys and size of the values that will ever be seen over the whole lifetime of the process is ok. If not, you can just clear the dictionary when its count goes over 10k or so. This is a very crude form of cache bounding.

Comment: Regarding cache trimming: There are more sophisticated solutions, but if you don't *need* much, then don't *do* much. Simplicity is a sound design goal.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, the use of TPL as a technology here is not really important, this is just a straight up concurrency problem. You're trying to protect access to a shared resource (the cached data) and, to do that, the only approach *is* to lock. Either that or, if the cache entry does not already exist, you could allow all incoming threads to generate it and then subsequent requesters benefit from the cached value once it's stored, but there's little value in that if the resource is slow/expensive to generate and cache.

Perhaps some more details will make it clear on exactly why you're trying to accomplish this without a lock. I'll happily to revise my answer if more detail makes it clearer what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Drew. I've updated my earlier question to remove the "avoid lock".